# Using a scaffolding/template tool like cookiecutter to check that directory structure and filename conventions are being followed?

Tags: python, templates, project, scaffolding, cookiecutter

I have searched and searched to find the tool that I need but I can't seem to find one.  I'm sure it exists though, so I will explain my issue and hopefully someone can help me.

Cookiecutter and other scaffolding tools create an initial project folder structure, filenames, etc. when starting a new project.  These automate a boring process but also ensure consistency.

I have an issue whereby I create a new project with multiple people working on it. It can be setup correctly but not everyone will then follow the convention, which is very frustrating and leads to errors, versioning problems and an inability for people to re-trace or recreate work they have done. I have decided I need to check that people are adhering to the convention once the project is underway.  This is another boring, laborious task that could be automated with a clever tool.

I would like a tool that not only sets up the initial project from template, but can also be run at various intervals to determine if a naming structure is being followed or not. I can then get a quick understanding of where the violations have occurred and I can address it with the person involved.

I've looked at cookiecutter which will certainly be suitable for the initial setup, but I wonder if there is another tool I am missing that will subsequently help me check that conventions are being followed?  If not I am sure I can modify cookiecutter to get it to do what I want, but an off-the-shelf solution would be ideal.

I should note that these are not necessarily text files with code. There will be versions of datasets, large binary files, some scripting files (python/matlab), images, etc. The naming convention then becomes important because I am using it for versioning, search and other problems that git simply solves.